# Can not config mongodb in Qt creator

Tags: c++, mongodb, qt, mongo-cxx-driver

Hello I am using Qt creator 4.6.0 and MongoDB 4.0 in windows 10 and I have already installed mongo-cxx-dirver-r3.3.0 ([c++ drivers](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/) for mongodb). The problem is,

```
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
```

whenever I include this file for making connection. But it was giving error,

> error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bsoncxx/config/config.hpp':
>   No such file or directory. (in both .hpp config.hpp is included).

But whenever i check in directory of Driver there is no config.hpp file but i found config.hpp.in.

Comment: How did you install `bsoncxx`?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour yes, in c++ driver both things(mongocxx and bsoncxx) are install. I just extract zip file and put with project folder and set relative path in .pro file.

Comment: No my question is how you specifically installed the driver. Which commands did you execute? What driver version have you installed.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Read question carefully, i m using win 10. so no need to use command for installation and already mention about version in question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build and install the driver before you can use it, not just unpack the archive and try to use those files. The `config.hpp.in` file is a template from which the `config.h` file is created at build time. Please read the installation instructions: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/

Comment: yes , i read this document but i found installation for visual studio not for Qt creator.

Comment: We don't have a specific instructions for Qt Creator. You will need to learn how that IDE integrates with CMake based projects like mongocxx. It isn't possible for the maintainers of a library to know how every IDE in the world works.